# IndexOutOfRangeException in C# raytracing code during vec3_extract method

Tags: c#

I'm currently working on a raytracing project in C# and have encountered an IndexOutOfRangeException in a specific method, vec3_extract. This method is intended to extract elements from a double array based on a corresponding bool array. Despite adding checks to ensure that the conditions are met, the error persists.

Here is the relevant code:

```
namespace Image
{
    public partial class Form3 : Form
    {
        public Form3()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
            toolStripMenuItem4.TextDirection = ToolStripTextDirection.Vertical270;
            toolStripMenuItem5.TextDirection = ToolStripTextDirection.Vertical90;
            toolStripMenuItem6.TextDirection = ToolStripTextDirection.Vertical90;
            double[] Q = x.Concat(y).Concat(Enumerable.Repeat(0.0, h)).ToArray();
            double[] color = raytrace(E, vec3_norm(vec3_sub(Q, E)), scene);
            Bitmap bmp = new Bitmap(w, h);
            for (int i = 0; i < w; i++)
            {
                for (int j = 0; j < h; j++)
                {
                    int index = i * h + j;
                    Color c = Color.FromArgb(
                        (int)(255 * Math.Clamp(color[3 * index], 0, 1)),
                        (int)(255 * Math.Clamp(color[3 * index + 1], 0, 1)),
                        (int)(255 * Math.Clamp(color[3 * index + 2], 0, 1))
                    );
                    bmp.SetPixel(i, j, c);
                }
            }
            pictureBox1.Image = bmp;
        }

        private void Form3_FormClosing(object sender, FormClosingEventArgs e)
        {
            Environment.Exit(0);
        }
        static double FARAWAY = 1.0e39;

        static double[] vec3_add(double[] v1, double[] v2)
        {
            return new double[] { v1[0] + v2[0], v1[1] + v2[1], v1[2] + v2[2] };
        }

        static double[] vec3_mul(double[] v, double other)
        {
            return new double[] { v[0] * other, v[1] * other, v[2] * other };
        }

        static double[] vec3_sub(double[] v1, double[] v2)
        {
            return new double[] { v1[0] - v2[0], v1[1] - v2[1], v1[2] - v2[2] };
        }

        static double vec3_dot(double[] v1, double[] v2)
        {
            return v1[0] * v2[0] + v1[1] * v2[1] + v1[2] * v2[2];
        }

        static double vec3_abs(double[] v)
        {
            return vec3_dot(v, v);
        }

        static double[] vec3_norm(double[] v)
        {
            double mag = Math.Sqrt(vec3_abs(v));
            return vec3_mul(v, 1.0 / (mag == 0 ? 1 : mag));
        }

        static double[] vec3_components(double[] v)
        {
            return v;
        }

        static double[] vec3_extract(double[] v, bool[] cond)
        {
            return new double[] { cond[0] ? v[0] : 0, cond[1] ? v[1] : 0, cond[2] ? v[2] : 0 };
        }

        static double[][] vec3_place(double[] v, bool[] cond)
        {
            double[][] result = new double[3][];
            result[0] = new double[cond.Length];
            result[1] = new double[cond.Length];
            result[2] = new double[cond.Length];

            for (int i = 0; i < cond.Length; i++)
            {
                result[0][i] = cond[i] ? v[0] : 0;
                result[1][i] = cond[i] ? v[1] : 0;
                result[2][i] = cond[i] ? v[2] : 0;
            }

            return result;
        }

        static double[] raytrace(double[] O, double[] D, double[][] scene, int bounce = 0)
        {
            double[] distances = scene.Select(s => s_intersect(O, D, s)).ToArray();
            double nearest = distances.Min();
            double[] color = new double[] { 0, 0, 0 };

            for (int i = 0; i < scene.Length; i++)
            {
                double[] s = scene[i];
                double d = distances[i];
                bool[] hit = new bool[] { d != FARAWAY && d == nearest };

                if (hit.Any())
                {
                    double[] dc = vec3_extract(D, hit);
                    double[] Oc = vec3_extract(O, hit);
                    double[] Dc = vec3_extract(D, hit);
                    double[] cc = s_light(Oc, Dc, dc[0], scene, bounce, s);
                    color = vec3_add(color, vec3_place(cc, hit)[0]);
                }
            }

            return color;
        }

        static double s_intersect(double[] O, double[] D, double[] s)
        {
            double[] temp = vec3_sub(O, s);
            double b = 2 * vec3_dot(D, temp);
            double c = vec3_abs(s) + vec3_abs(O) - 2 * vec3_dot(s, O) - (s[1] * s[1]);
            double disc = (b * b) - (4 * c);
            double sq = Math.Sqrt(Math.Max(0, disc));
            double h0 = (-b - sq) / 2;
            double h1 = (-b + sq) / 2;
            double h = (h0 > 0 && h0 < h1) ? h0 : h1;
            bool pred = (disc > 0) && (h > 0);
            return pred ? h : FARAWAY;
        }

        static double[] s_light(double[] O, double[] D, double d, double[][] scene, int bounce, double[] s)
        {
            double[] M = vec3_add(O, vec3_mul(D, d));
            double[] N = vec3_mul(vec3_sub(M, s), 1.0 / s[1]);
            double[] toL = vec3_norm(vec3_sub(L, M));
            double[] toO = vec3_norm(vec3_sub(E, M));
            double[] nudged = vec3_add(M, vec3_mul(N, 0.0001));

            double[] light_distances = scene.Select(scene_obj => s_intersect(nudged, toL, scene_obj)).ToArray();
            double light_nearest = light_distances.Min();
            bool seelight = light_distances[Array.IndexOf(scene, s)] == light_nearest;

            double[] color = new double[] { 0.05, 0.05, 0.05 };
            double lv = Math.Max(vec3_dot(N, toL), 0);
            color = vec3_add(color, vec3_mul(new double[] { s[2], s[2], s[2] }, lv * (seelight ? 1 : 0)));
            if (bounce < 2)
            {
                double[] rayD = vec3_norm(vec3_sub(D, vec3_mul(N, 2 * vec3_dot(N, D))));
                color = vec3_add(color, vec3_mul(raytrace(nudged, rayD, scene, bounce + 1), s[3]));
            }

            double phong = vec3_dot(N, vec3_norm(vec3_add(toL, toO)));
            color = vec3_add(color, vec3_mul(new double[] { 1, 1, 1 }, Math.Pow(Math.Clamp(phong, 0, 1), 50) * (seelight ? 1 : 0)));

            return color;
        }

        static double[][] scene = new double[][]
        {
        new double[] { 0.75, 0.1, 1, 0.6, 0, 0, 1, 0.5 },
        new double[] { -0.75, 0.1, 2.25, 0.6, 0.5, 0.223, 0.5, 0.5 },
        new double[] { -2.75, 0.1, 3.5, 0.6, 1, 0.572, 0.184, 0.5 },
        new double[] { 0, -99999.5, 0, 99999, 0.75, 0.75, 0.75, 0.25 }
        };

        static int w = 400;
        static int h = 300;
        static double[] L = { 5, 5, -10 };
        static double[] E = { 0, 0.35, -1 };
        static double r = w / (double)h;
        static double[] S = { -1, 1 / r + 0.25, 1, -1 / r + 0.25 };

        static double[] x = Enumerable.Repeat(S[0], w).ToArray();
        static double[] y = Enumerable.Repeat(S[1], h).ToArray();
    }
}
```

Comment: On which line does the error occur?

Comment: On `vec3_extract` method.

Comment: Please see [What is an IndexOutOfRangeException / ArgumentOutOfRangeException and how do I fix it?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/20940979/3744182).  If that isn't enough to help, please try to [edit] your code down to a [mcve] that can be pasted into a console app, built, and debugged.

Comment: A simple step through of your code would help you identify an `IndexOutOfRangeException`. But I would say that the issue is that `vec3_extract(double[],bool[])` is expecting the bool array to have 3 values, which it doesn't when you call it in `raytrace`. This line in raytrace, `bool[] hit = new bool[] { d != FARAWAY && d == nearest };` initializes a bool array with only 1 value.